# Drone CI secrets not populating

Tags: docker, drone.io, docker-secrets

I am trying to push a docker image into a private registry in Drone 0.8.5 and it works when I hardcode username and password into the pipeline however I have tried adding both the registry details in the registry tab and as secrets.

Registry Pipeline

```
docker-registry-push:
  image: plugins/docker
  repo: registry.domain.com:5000/app
  registry: registry.domain.com:5000
  insecure: true
  pull: true
```

Fails with `no basic auth credentials`

Finally I've tried variable substitution. (with $REGISTRY_USERNAME and $$REGISTRY_USERNAME variables. All result in a error `msg="Error authenticating: exit status 1"`

```
docker-registry-push:
  image: plugins/docker
  repo: registry.domain.com:5000/app
  registry: registry.domain.com:5000
  secrets:
    - source: registry_username
      target: username
    - source: registry_password
      target: password
  insecure: true
  pull: true
```

another attempt

```
docker-registry-push:
  image: plugins/docker
  repo: registry.domain.com:5000/app
  registry: registry.domain.com:5000
  username: ${REGISTRY_USERNAME}  
  password: ${REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
  secrets: [ registry_username, registry_password ]
  insecure: true
  pull: true
```

It is really frustrating. I need to add secrets for Rancher accesskey secretkey also after this via the correct method.

I have read other topics and the drone docs and am still stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secrets need to be injected into the docker container via the environment with the names `docker_username` and and `docker_password`.

Your `.drone.yml` file should look something like this:

```
pipeline:
  docker:
    image: plugins/docker
    repo: username/app
    registry: registry.domain.com:5000
    insecure: true
    pull: true
    secrets:
      - source: registry_username
        target: docker_username
      - source: registry_password
        target: docker_password
```

See the [drone plugin docs](http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-docker/) for more configuration options.

Comment: Ah ok - so I misread the plugin docs. That is working now. Thank-you so much. I really appreciate the helping hand guys!!

Answer (score 0):

here is to manage **drone secret key** http://docs.drone.io/manage-secrets/#pull-requests

also, you might wanna consider using `.netrc` inside `Dockerfile` on your build, so your credential is embeded inside of your docker images

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just tried that however it results in the same error :-(

Comment: what have you tried..? and what's the error..? i've experiencing the same problem as yours a years ago. .